# To what extent can the natural numbers be covered under this Borromean type scheme?

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility, integers

Let ***l*** and ***m*** be consecutive integers that will be multiplied together. For any such "*pronic*" combination let ***l*** represent the floor of the square root of a whole number constructed as (***lm***) + **S**.

For the sake of clarity let us refer to any ***lm*** combination as a "*base"*. The question seeks to determine the circumstances under which it is possible to construct three *"interlocked"* whole numbers, where modulo their individual base they are all congruent to **S**, subject to certain conditions.

Therefore, if we let **D,E** and **F** be whole numbers constructed in each case as "***base***" + **S**, and we take ***a,b*** and ***c*** to be integers such that: **D** = ***ab***,  **E** = ***ac***,  and **F** = ***bc***, we have a constraint.

Regardless of whether or not any of ***a,b*** and ***c*** are prime divisors, if we impose the conditions of construction as detailed above, is it possible to eventually represent all natural numbers under what might be termed this ***Borromean*** style of relationship? We may obviously allow **S** to range over the integers for this, thereby allowing for the creation of subsets of the naturals to which the investigation may apply.

**Edit 04/12/21**

**Background**

The motivation for posing this question lies in the fact that the relationship type features as a distinct phenomenon within a novel methodology designed to offer a two factor decomposition for particular elements contained within groupings of the natural numbers.

If we construct groups where every member is composed as **($m^2 - m$) + S**, for a certain constant **S**, it is possible to locate some of these values in sequences that facilitate a potentially elementary decomposition of an individual member without the need to employ a division algorithm.

The *"location"* amounts to seeking and determining the index point of an occurrence of the value within a set of specially constructed curves.  When we juxtapose adjacent curves we are able to identify two whole numbers that share a common factor. It is possible to combine the cofactors of both numbers so that they render a value in a third (i.e. *higher order*) curve.

The point is that *without knowing the relationship beforehand*, if we are able to identify the location of any one of **D,E or F** within an appropriate curve it will *reveal* the identity of the other two, and facilitate decomposition of all three.

This procedure can be extended in several ways. What is at issue is the difficulty in getting a handle on the growth in the curve structures.

**Comment**

A quick and dirty answer to the question would be to conclude that it is not feasible to organise the natural numbers in a three way relationship as outlined without some modification of the constraints.  By this we allude to the fact that the ***base*** might necessarily have to *stretch* so that it is no longer *pronic* in shape (i.e. ***l*** and ***m*** are no longer consecutive).

Just how far might we have to stretch in order to be able to account for all natural numbers in a regimented three way relationship of this type?

**A limited illustration of how this question relates to factoring.**

It is impractical to present a condensed version of the factoring methodology here, since this itself has been in development for several years and there is much detail to go through.  Suffice to say that while naive in its current implementation, it may offer in time, a useful addition to the arsenal of existing methodologies for factoring whole numbers.  It appears to be novel. Overall it is a sieve methodology that concerns itself with finding two non-trivial factors for a whole number without determining whether such factors are prime or composite.

At the moment it is possible to employ the sieve using strictly defined curves that are of general application i.e. the curves will permit any change of **S** in the structure of the polynomial, and may facilitate the discovery of factors for numbers defined by the construction.  The whole thing has been borne out of a desire to be able to *explain* away the composites that are encountered when we study the celebrated prime generating polynomials; the net effect however is far-reaching.

So if we turn to **($m^2 - m$) + 41** as an example, we are able to gather results from the sieving processes like these: (**S** = **41**)

Curve 2, index point 2,  ***m*** = **83**,  product **D** = **6847**,
factor 1 = ***a*** = **41**,     factor 2 = ***b*** = **167**

Curve 3, index point 2,  ***m*** = **124**,  product  **E** = **15293**,
factor 1 = ***a*** = **41**,     factor 2 = ***c*** = **373**

Higher curve 2, index point 2, ***m*** = **250**,  product **F** = **62291**,
factor 1 = ***b***  =**167**,     factor 2 = ***c*** =**373**

The curves are built in an entirely deterministic fashion from an additive routine.  If we take the common index points and consider these as a rank, we may jump into any curve at any rank and factor the corresponding values at will.  Because of the inter-relationship of the curves we can discover factors by simple algebraic processes.

The process is subject to a potentially time consuming search for any particular ***m*** given the need to iterate through curves.  While the method demonstrates a startling ability to deliver factors for the particular numbers that it presently captures, its ability to offer up a factorisation for any arbitrary number will be dependent on whether or not the higher curves can continue to be developed in such a way as to make them easily identifiable and computable.

Comment: This question is pretty incomprehensible as written. What does it mean to "achieve cover of the natural numbers" here (and for that matter, what does "to what extent" mean)? What precisely is your question?

Comment: @ Noah I have edited the text to try and address your comments.

Comment: What does "represent every natural number in a tripartite relationship subject to these constructions" mean? E.g. take $S=2$. Is the number $4$ "represented" in the way you want?

Comment: The question is still pretty incomprehensible and reads like quackery. Can you give an example of the phenomenon you're trying to describe?

Comment: An example of numbers $a,b,c,D,E,F,S$ that satisfy your requirements from the first few paragraphs might be clarifying.

Comment: @Karl - I trust the illustration is now clear? The construction constraint applies to values D,E and F for every rank (index point).  The only thing that changes is that every rank has an interlocked set of factors that are specific to that rank.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but an attempt to clarify your question by making it shorter and more precise.

For $n\in\Bbb N$, define $s(n)=n-\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor(\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor+1)$. For example, $s(7)=1$.

If $a,b,c$ are natural numbers satisfying $s(ab)=s(ac)=s(bc)$, we call the set $\{ab,ac,bc\}$ *interlocking*.

For example, $(a,b,c)=(41,167,373)$ generates the interlocking set $\{6847,15293,62291\}\subset s^{-1}(41)$.

Question: **Can every natural number be found in an interlocking set?**

Context: I'm developing a sieve-related factoring algorithm that involves enumerating the set $s^{-1}(k)=\{m(m+1)+k:m\in\Bbb N,m\ge|k|\}$ and identifying values that interlock in the way described above. I believe the interlocking may help "explain away" the composite numbers that occur as values of prime-generating polynomials.

Comment: It is refreshing to have some engagement with the substance of the question at least.  While the form of expression is welcome (pinning things to the notion of the original "pronic" base), I hope the original attempt and background steers the reader beyond the summary you make of the "context".  This is a neglected area of research that if handled with the right tools has potential to illuminate the construction of all composite numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I just think your writing style is unconventionally wordy in a way that (for most readers here) obfuscates the precise content of your question. It helps to get the precise question formulated as efficiently as possible before bogging readers down with vague qualitative thoughts and definitions.